# EXISTS and NOT EXISTS in a correlated subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, exists, correlated-subquery

I've been trying to work out how to do a particular query for a day or so now and it has gotten to the point where I need some outside help. Hence my question.

Given the following data;

```
DECLARE @Data AS TABLE
(
      OrgId INT,
      ThingId INT
)

DECLARE @ReplacementData AS TABLE
(
      OldThingId INT,
      NewThingId INT
)

INSERT INTO @Data (OrgId, ThingId)
VALUES (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4),
       (2, 1), (2, 4),
       (3, 3), (3, 4)

INSERT INTO @ReplacementData (OldThingId, NewThingId)
VALUES (3, 4), (2, 5)
```

I want to find any organisation that has a "thing" that has been replaced as denoted in the `@ReplacementData` table variable. I'd want to see the org id, the thing it is that they have that has been replaced and the id of the thing that should replace it. So for example given the data above, I should see;

```
Org id, Thing Id, Replacement Thing Id org doesn't have but should have 
1, 2, 5 -- As Org 1 has 2, but not 5
```

I've had many attempts at trying to get this working, and I just can't seem to get my head around how to go about it. The following are a couple of my attempts, but I think I am just way off;

```
-- Attempt using correlated subqueries and EXISTS clauses
-- Show all orgs that have the old thing, but not the new thing
-- Ideally, limit results to OrgId, OldThingId and the NewThingId that they should now have too
SELECT *
  FROM @Data d
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM @Data oldstuff
                WHERE oldstuff.OrgId = d.OrgId
                  AND oldstuff.ThingId IN
                (SELECT OldThingID
                   FROM @ReplacementData))
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM @Data oldstuff
                WHERE oldstuff.OrgId = d.OrgId
                  AND oldstuff.ThingId IN
                (SELECT NewThingID
                   FROM @ReplacementData))


   -- Attempt at using a JOIN to only include those old things that the org has (via the where clause)
   -- Also try exists to show missing new things. 
   SELECT *
      FROM @Data d
 LEFT JOIN @ReplacementData rd ON rd.OldThingId = d.ThingId
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
              FROM @Data dta
        INNER JOIN @ReplacementData rep ON rep.NewThingId = dta.ThingId
             WHERE dta.OrgId = d.OrgId
    )
   AND rd.OldThingId IS NOT NULL
```

Any help on this is much appreciated. I may well be going about it completely wrong, so please let me know if there is a better way of tackling this type of problem.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on the requirements here.  Can you elaborate on the rules?  "I'd want to see the org id, the thing it is that they have that has been replaced and the id of the thing that should replace it" isn't clear to me.  I get the 1,2,5 -- but why not 1,3,4 and 3,3,4???

Comment: Not 1, 3, 4 because org 1 has things 3 and 4. Same with org 3. It has both 3 and 4. I want to find organisations that have an oldthing, but not yet a newthing.

Comment: Got it... answer coming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out and let me know.

```
DECLARE @Data AS TABLE
(
      OrgId INT,
      ThingId INT
)

DECLARE @ReplacementData AS TABLE
(
      OldThingId INT,
      NewThingId INT
)

INSERT INTO @Data (OrgId, ThingId)
VALUES (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4),
       (2, 1), (2, 4),
       (3, 3), (3, 4)

INSERT INTO @ReplacementData (OldThingId, NewThingId)
VALUES (3, 4), (2, 5)

SELECT D.OrgId, RD.*
FROM @Data D 
JOIN @ReplacementData RD
   ON D.ThingId=RD.OldThingId
   LEFT OUTER JOIN @Data EXCLUDE
      ON D.OrgId = EXCLUDE.OrgId
      AND RD.NewThingId = EXCLUDE.ThingId
WHERE EXCLUDE.OrgId IS NULL
```

Comment: That is certainly looking very promising. I'll try it out when I get to work tomorrow and let you know how I get on. 
Thanks so much.

Comment: I finally got back to testing this out, and it works a treat. I never tend to use self joins and I think it was the missing piece of the puzzle for me in this one. I get too caught up in trying to construct my query around how I would describe the problem (ie. Show me all orgs who have the old thing (exists), but don't have the new thing (not exists)). Your method is heaps nicer. Thanks again.